# Git merge missed file to mark as conflict

Tags: git, merge

I dont know what i have done or I'm missing something but `git merge` skip some files that I'm pretty sure there is one file that should be conflict (I am not sure if there is other files missed too).

I have 2 branches:

- **feature/A**

  - file test.txt (200 lines)
  - file test2.txt (100 lines)
- **feature/B**

  - file test.txt (250 lines)
  - file test2.txt (130 lines)

And then I run this command from branch `feature/A`:

`git merge --no-ff feature/B`

But it says only file test2.txt that remarked as conflict. `test.txt` still same with `200 lines` and no warning about it and it makes my codes error because there is config lost (unmerge).

What I have to do?

Comment: at least give me a reason why i get a vote down. as far as i know I already mentions and try the best to explain what I am facing with in simple way. geez

Comment: Did test.txt change on the feature/B branch (compared to the common base between the branches)?